# Open Google Doc in Libreoffice with Gnome file integration

Tags: nautilus, libreoffice, google, google-drive

I signed into my Google account in Gnome, and I can access my files from nautilus, however opening any document opens google docs in my browser directly, and opening in LibreOffice Writer results in it opening the raw JSON which isn't formatted properly.

The file type is `application/vnd.google-apps.document type (application/vnd.google-apps.document)`, and I can't seem to find a way to open these documents in Libreoffice, `ooo2gd` is severely outdated and doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Does tis resoource help answer your question? https://classroom.synonym.com/open-google-drive-libreoffice-18046.html

Comment: No, there's no official drive client for linux, and the GNOME integration automatically adds the files. The problem is that LibreOffice can't open the docs format file, and the ooo2gd extension was last updated in 2011 and does not work anymore.

Comment: Kubuntu has something for Dophin, but it doesn't open the .odt's.